# Как подключить Google-client-Api с помощью webpack?

Tags: javascript, api, webpack

Я новичок в вебпак и не могу никак прикрутить к проекту скрипт.
До этого я делал как указано здесь, то есть тегами <скрипт> в где второй скрипт после загрузки вызывает первый.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Но в вебпак ничего не получается. Буду признателен за любую помощь.